# TCP Server in C/C++: Send timeout message

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, server

I was looking for a way to set a timeout for one connection and I've already found some very good answers, but timeout alone isn't enough for me.

I want my last server -> client message to be an announcement about timeout. I don't want to suddenly interrupt connection with client, leaving them clueless.

What I'm looking for:

```
if ( /* should timeout now */ )
{
   char timeout_msg [] = "Connection timed out";
   if (send(sock_fd,  timeout_msg, sizeof(timeout_msg), 0) < 0)
   {
      perror("Sending problem");
      return whatever;
   }

   //actually time out now
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Something like that should be fine.  When you close the TCP socket, the OS will maintain it for a while to try to ensure that every last bit of data gets through to the other side.

Comment: The problem with this kind of thing is that presumably you're going to send it after a read timeout, which already means that either the peer or the network is malfunctioning. So there is no guarantee you will even be able to send the message, or that the peer will react to it correctly. If it could do so, the timeout shouldn't have happened at all. It seems quite pointless to me. Just close the connection and let the peer make of that what it will.

Comment: Further to EJP's point, if your send buffer happens to be full (which is more likely than usual given the earlier timeout), or even nearly full, the attempt to send the timeout message may not have room to be [fully] enqueued, which compromises the best-effort logic mentioned by jschutlz410.

Comment: And further to my own point, what 's supposed to happen if the timeout message times out? You can't send an error message to a misbehaving peer.